# how to get normalized coordinates of mouse position in MouseRegion

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `MouseRegion` for capturing mouse hover events using `onHover` callback. It is easy to get mouse position in pixels. But I need to get normalized coordinates, such that the top-left corner would have `(0.0, 0.0)` and bottom-right corner would have `(1.0, 1.0)`. But I struggle with this because I cannot find any way how to get the `MouseRegion`'s width and height to the callback function so that I could calculate the normalized coordinates. Note that the widget does not have a fixed size because it is a part of a complex layout.

Is there any solution to get the normalized coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the current position with maxLength.

```dart
body: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => MouseRegion(
    onHover: (event) {
      final width = constraints.maxWidth;
      final height = constraints.maxHeight;
      final dx = event.localPosition.dx;
      final dy = event.localPosition.dy;
      final x = dx / width;
      final y = dy / height;

      print('x: $x, y: $y');
    },
```

Comment: The docs https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html say "If it has a child, this widget defers to the child for sizing behavior. If it does not have a child, it grows to fit the parent instead."

So it seems that your solution will work well as long as it has not child or the child fills the whole parent. Is that right?

Comment: well in flutter size goes up&  you likely have a child widget. Also the GestureDetector provides onHover, it depends on widget structure.